# I dropped my glasses. Would I say "My glasses fell on the floor" or "My glasses fell to the floor"

Tags: prepositions

Are 'fell to' and 'fell on' equivalent? What are the contexts in which they are both used?

Comment: "Fell on the floor" simply states that the glasses were dropped and they ended up on the floor.  "Fell to the floor" might be used, eg, if the glasses first were dropped on a chair seat and then, while trying to grab them, they were accidentally knocked off the chair and onto the floor.

Comment: I’m not sure I believe that “fell to the floor” requires an intermediate surface.  “Fell to the floor” simply means that they fell and they fell all the way to the floor (the floor is where they stopped)

Comment: Generally speaking, if a person falls to the floor, they are involved in the action. If they fall on the floor, they are not. And generally, things fall on the floor, not to the floor.

Comment: 'Fell on the floor' is the idiomatic way of saying what would to one unfamiliar with _idiomatic_ English be far more logically 'fell onto the floor' or 'fell to the floor'.  And 'fell to the ground' is indeed acceptable, but is in a far more formal register and connotes to a certain degree (see Lambie's comment) a volitional falling.

Comment: So, concentrating on 'fell to the floor'. (Glasses not person).  It sounds like that there is a requirement that they end up on the floor?  If i caught them, in flight,  could I still say "fell to the floor, but then I caught them"'?